# Using Nodeport to access api in pod Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-nodeport

I created a nodeport service on a port 12345, to access my api running on node 6666, deployed through a pod. The pod is deployed in multiple nodes.

```
 ports:
   - port: 8181
     targetPort: 6666
     nodePort: 12345
     protocol: TCP
```

In order to get the ip of the node, by running

```
   kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

the internal / external ip of the node was obtained.
Thus, the resulting curl command is

```
   http://<node internal ip>:12345/
```

The issue is that this is circulating all the nodes, running through the open port, everytime a ping is done.

How can I ensure that the ping, using the internal ip only hits one node and the pod service running on it?

Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Are you asking how to reduce the number of hops you see when you run the `ping` command against your node?

Comment: I have a pod running an api endpoint, deployed on multiple nodes. I declared a service as nodeport, to open the nodes for communication, so that I can ping the api, through the defined port (12345). The issue I faced was during the ping, it did not stick to the specific node, where the ip was mentioned, rather accessed all the nodes the pod-api was deployed on @jordanm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the above issue by adding the

```
 externalTrafficPolicy: "Local"
```

In the service definition. This way, the ping to the ip of the node, and to the api, did not go to other nodes, but rather was restricted locally to the node.